# Webservice task flow description language

Tags: xml, web-services, workflow, soa, business-process-management

Say I expose some functionality via a webservice. These methods each have their own reason to exist; black boxes that deliver some output based on some input. The method details are, of course, described in a WSDL file.

Now say a combination of service calls could represent a certain business process within an organization. Some sort of task/work flow. I would like to expose such a task/work flow to a consumer using some (XML?) format.

So, like a description of a webservice is delivered via a WSDL, I'm looking for (a) standard(s) that enables me to expose a task flow between certain webservice calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at BPMN2 is becoming the defacto standard and nowadays most of the BPM System vendors are adopting this language. If you are thinking to adopt one, you should know about BPMN2. You can take a look at jBPM5 for example, www.jbpm.org cheers

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_modeling, for example BPEL or XPDL. I would strongly suggest not requiring your clients to consume those languages though, but rather build a stateful business process service (for example using available BPM suites) that ensures that the underlying web service operations are called in the correct order.